# A 3 column HTML layout

Tags: html, css, layout

There are many many questions, answers and tutorials related to a 3 column design, but none of them have helped solve my particular problem.

I have two text inputs surrounding a select control, which I need to display in a single line. The problem stems from the fact that I use a jQuery library to style the controls. Both text inputs are designed to fill their parent container, but the center select is given a width specific to its content.

The normal way to handle this layout would be to use margins and floats, all of which require knowledge of the center columns width beforehand.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twifty/UUzE9/328/) is the closest solution I can find, but it still requires hard coded values. The `.content:width` is set on page load by javascript. Here I have given it a random value. The `.left, .right` widths have a hard coded value which I'd like to remove.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
    <div class='center'><div class='content'></div></div>
</div>

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    /* The width and display come from javascript. */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
}
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

I know this can easily be done using javascript, but I would prefer CSS only answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='center'><div class='content'></div></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    /* The width and display come from javascript. */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
}
.left, .right {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

The center has a fixed width and the side elements fill the space.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twifty/UUzE9/329/)

If not, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Flexboxes are pretty widely supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use bootstrap css : you have have an excellent system of grid that allows you to do whatever you want [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Comment: A grid system won't fix this as each column as a pre determined width.